# Avalonia validation - disable specific variable

Tags: c#, .net, validation, avalonia

The situation - user has to select a file path. But when toggle is on, user doesn't have to do it anymore. And I don't know how to make sure that apply button can be clicked on when path is not selected and toggle is on. I have tried all possible things but button is always locked, meaning user needs that path even when they don't actually need it.

Some examples of failed attempts:

```cs
this.ValidationRule(
                x => x.Path,
                val => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) && ReadPath is true,
                "Path cannot be empty."
                );

//tried the same thing but opposite, just in case
this.ValidationRule(
                x => x.Path,
                val => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) && ReadPath is false,
                "Path cannot be empty."
                );

if(ReadPath)
this.ValidationRule(
                x => x.Path,
                val => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val),
                "Path cannot be empty."
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) && ReadPath is false
```